# C++ Assignment composite operators vs simple operators combined with assignment operators

Tags: c++, optimization, operators, variable-assignment, composite

Someone can explain [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Constructions_and_destructions) practice to me?

```
// no
string s1("abc");
string s2 = s1 + " " + s1;

// yes
string s1("abc");
string s2 = s1;
s2 += " ";
s2 += s1;
```

> Typically, a simple operator creates a temporary object. In the example, the operator + creates temporary strings whose creation and destruction require much time.
>
> On the contrary, the equivalent code using the += operator does not
>   create temporary objects.

With composite operator you can remove one of the operands (a little optimization) but in this case?

```
while(something)
{
    total+=(a-b)*c;
}
```

I should use another variable (otherwise the result would be wrong), to prevent the temporary object?

Comment: Before making optimization changes, profile.  After making optimization changes, profile again.  Without profiling, you are merely blindly guessing.

Comment: I assume that all in the `while`-loop are primitive types. Then this should not make a meaningful difference since the creation of primitives is very inexpensive. Especially if you introduce a new variable this variable would have to be instantiated as well, so I see absolutely no gain. Furthermore every modern compiler should be able to optimize code like that into its best form. I suggest you do not try to optimise this unless you are absolutely sure (by profiling) that this is your bottleneck.